# Twilio return method as POST value

Tags: macos, python-2.7, api, twilio

I am trying to build on a test Twilio script in order that the POST request can just use values returned by method is a script.
The values are set as environmental variables and I have checked that they are correct in the Python shell using the same command as the script.
Python 2.7 being used.
The environmental variables are stored as strings and return as such.

```
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient
import os

ACCOUNT_SID = os.environ['ACCOUNT_SID']
AUTH_TOKEN = os.environ['AUTH_TOKEN']
client = TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN)

def target_number():
    return os.environ['TARGET_NUMBER']

def my_number():
    return os.environ['MY_NUMBER']

message = client.messages.create(
    body="foo bar",  # Message body, if any
    to=target_number(),
   from_=my_number(),
)
print message.body
```

I am getting the following error:

```
python my_twilio_testing_script.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_twilio_testing_script.py", line 19, in <module>
    to=target_number(),
  File "my_twilio_testing_script.py", line 9, in target_number
    return os.environ['TARGET_NUMBER']
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'TARGET_NUMBER'
```

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It appears that some of your environment variables are working, otherwise the script would blow up when you set the account SID and auth token.

So it seems that maybe TARGET_NUMBER is perhaps not set. In the terminal window in which you run the script, are you able to perform the following bash command:

```
$ echo $TARGET_NUMBER
```

Does that show the number you expect? If not, you may need to export the environment variable again.

Comment: Yeah I checked that. It seems that I just can't use the return value of functions within those parameters.
Haven't found a workaround as yet, seems strange that it can't be done though.
A solution may be to extract the Twilio call into a function and loop it and as part of the loop to keep changing the environmental variables.
I have not yet had a chance to try this though